# Как обрабатывать большой ответ с сервера в vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, api, axios, vuex

Ситуация следующая, с бека приходит относительно большой единый объект данных около 70кб. Объект имеет довольно большую вложенность и ветвление. Я во vuex запрашиваю этот объект в action при помощи axios при инициализации всего vue приложения вызываю этот action и помещаю в state. Чтобы было более удобно работать с отельными сущностями из этого объекта, я разделяю его при помощи различных getters, но я столкнулся с проблемами когда данные не успевают загрузится и вылетают ошибки при загрузки проекта, так же в каждом геттере я проверяю на существование сущности и если она есть (то есть загрузилась) возвращаю ее. Вопрос в следующем как оптимизировать и какие практики применить в данном случае? Я понимаю что сейчас это реализовано очень плохо, но не нашел ответа как это отрефачить. Или же это проблема backend и там надо разделять api? Буду рад любым советам!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ничего не нашли по тому что каждая задача индивидуальна.

В том что Вы описали самом по себе проблемы нет никакой, если данные нужно только читать, то деление на геттеры разумно, ну а проверка на существование само-собой разумеющееся, если вы не используется опциональное связывание (?.).

Однако если вам не удобно работать с таким большим объектом разделите его в экшене как вам удобно. Есть множество средств для этого например: [vuex-orm](https://github.com/vuex-orm/vuex-orm), [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr).

Что касается вашего предположения о том что это проблема бэка. От части вы правы, грамотное разбиение на сущности может предотвратить слишком большую вложенность.